# tapply used on 2 variables from a data frame gives an error message

Tags: r

I have an 87 x 1 DataFrame called df2 containing Day and Day2.

```
> tail(df2,5)
   Day      Day2    Date         Imp Clicks  credit
53   6  Saturday 20SEP03        4128     27   $2.88
54   7    Sunday 21SEP03        5911     50   $4.99
55   1    Monday 22SEP03       15139     29   $3.25
56   2   Tuesday 23SEP03        9444     49   $7.15
57   3 Wednesday 24SEP03        4987     38   $4.68
```

I want to form a 7 x 3 matrix where the rows are day2 and the columns are imp clicks and credit. I'm getting an error that the arguments must be of the same length. They're not. What am I misinterpreting about this error message?

```
> tapply(df2,list(df2$Day,df2$Imp),mean)
Error in tapply(df2, list(df2$Day, df2$Imp), mean) : 
  arguments must have same length
> tapply(df2,list(df2$DayofWeek,df2$Imp),mean)
Error in tapply(df2, list(df2$Day2, df2$Imp), mean) : 
  arguments must have same length
>
```

Thank you.  MM

Answer (score 1):

In the OP's code, first argument is the entire dataset instead of a numeric column

According to `?tapply`

> X - an R object for which a split method exists. Typically vector-like, allowing subsetting with [

From the data showed, it seems 'Clicks' to be `numeric`

```
tapply(df2$Clicks,list(df2$Day,df2$Impressions),mean)
```

---

Also, the 'credit' column is not numeric as there is a `$` as prefix.  It needs to be removed and change the column to `numeric` with `as.numeric`

```
df2$credit <- as.numeric(sub("$", "", df2$credit, fixed = TRUE))
```

and then use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(cbind(credit, Clicks)~ Day + Impressions, df2, FUN = mean)
```

---

Or another approach is `by`

```
by(df2[c('credit', 'Clicks')], df2[c('Day', 'Impressions'], FUN = colMeans)
```

Comment: I had made those changes to numeric. I will study this. Thanks.

Comment: I really messed this up. I started over and now have 3 arrays of data called I,C, and R. The arrays are each 7 x1. Now all I have to do is to combine them into a 7 x 3 table and I am done.

Comment: @MaryA.Marion Sorry, not clear. I guess you know the importance of a reproducible example and expected output (from posting more than 60 questions).

Comment: It is not my data so I need to alter it before submitting. I had not expected to ask so many questions. Regarding output well I take one day at a time and no I don't know the ramifications.  I am learning a lot in a short period of time and frankly need to read the help files better. Cheers.  MM